# PDF file is not opening with IP but opening properly when addressed to domain

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf, hyperlink

I have my website in 2 locations 1 is in cloud just setting up sen=cond one is in godaddy

Example: **Dummy Links**

the link from cloud is this:

> http://133.11.10.100/cdp/resumes/CV%20and%20Cover%20Letter%20Fernando%20Maquiaveli%20-%20English-h.pdf28-Aug-2014:02:08:57

the link from godaddy is this:

> http://website.com/cdp/resumes/CV%20and%20Cover%20Letter%20Fernando%20Maquiaveli%20-%20English-h.pdf28-Aug-2014:02:08:57

From the above 2 link second one is working fine 1st one which is new it is not working so what could be the possible issue..?

I would like to know what is the standard way to store any file name in database..?

this is the issue im getting:
[image: URL IS NOT COMING CORRECT]

Comment: avoid using spaces in file names. Check with host regarding problem. Nothing anyone here can do

Comment: Okay.! Actually user will upload the file with any name that may contain spaces or any charecters do you want me to write filename as i like.? Or is there any standard there to follow..?

Comment: can always fix names during upload processing

Comment: how can i avoid duplicate file entries.?

Comment: check if file exists before overwriting it. Question is too broad without a lot more details about your stack/ cloud service